# iOS - providing color selection in app settings bundle

Tags: ios, application-settings

I like the iOS app settings bundle functionality, but there doesn't appear to be a built-in color selection control. The closest I've seen is enumerating several colors and presenting them as a list to select from.

Some questions:

- am I correct, no built-in color selection control?
- is there a way to use attributed strings within the settings bundle?
- the DTD indicates base64 data is allowed, can this be used to encode attributed strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- am I correct, no built-in color selection control? - **Yes, no built-in control.**
- is there a way to use attributed strings within the settings bundle? - **No.**
- the DTD indicates base64 data is allowed, can this be used to encode attributed strings? - **Not sure probably not.**